# Start emitting after another observable emitted its first item

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, observable, rx-java2, reactivex

I have this simple usecase that I can't seem to figure out.

Given 2 observables, A and B

A starts emitting items after B emits it's first item, and B can continue to emit items, which should no longer affect A.

I need this because A needs the first value emitted by B to start emitting.

I've tried both skipUntil and startWith to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) can help you do what you want:

```java
Observable<Integer> createA(Observable<Integer> B) {
    return B.take(1).flatMap(b -> {
        /* replace with your Observable A implementation here */
        BehaviorSubject<Integer> subjectA = BehaviorSubject.create();
        return subjectA;
    });
}
```

This method returns an Observable `A`, which begins emitting only after it has been initialized with the first value emitted by Observable `B`.

Comment: This works, btw how would you do it if you had 2 or more observables that depended on the result of the first emission of B? just duplicate the code and replace A with C,D,E...?

Comment: @Linxy Yes, you could replicate the code. I've had a similar situation where I needed a lot of methods that all depended on initialization data that came from an Observable. I created one method `getInit()` that returns the initialization Observable (essentially returning `B.take(1)` above), and then the other dependent methods are basically `return getInit().flatMap(...)`. So, same pattern, they just use a method to get the init Observable rather than having it passed in. It probably depends more on the specifics of how you are using each of the Observables.